# How can I hardcode specific server names in powershell script

Tags: powershell, hardcode

I want to reboot specific servers, I am using findstr to find specific servers in the list of 1000's of servers, however, is there any way I can hardcode servernames in a script so the script only run on a particular set of remote servers? Also, how to use for each against array variable. For e.g is below method correct?

```
$serverlist = "server1,server2,server3"

for each ($server in $serverlist){  $serverboot= gwmi win32_operatingsystem -comp $server
$serverboot.Reboot
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a list of your servers for this the coma (`,`) is the array operator in PowerShell :

```
$serverlist = "server1","server2","server3"
```

Now `$serverlist` is an array or a collection you can use.

Then you pipe this list in the `Foreach-Object` Cmdlet that allow you to execute a scriptblock for each element in the list. `$_` represent the current element. `;` is the instruction seprator :

```
$serverlist | ForEach-Object {$serverboot= gwmi win32_operatingsystem -comp $_; $serverboot.Reboot()}
```

Comment: I tried the above script, it did not work and kept on asking me:  cmdlet Foreach-object at command pipeline position 1  Please supply values for the following parameters: Process[0] .... I have defined $serverlist = "server1","server2"

Comment: Sorry,, I gorgot the `()` because I don't reboot my servers, but for me it works till there.

Comment: the actual issue what I have found is not declaring -Process and mentioning what to do on each object...i.e we have to reboot so the working command is: $serverlist | ForEach-Object -Process {....